# preg_replace(): The /e modifer is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead php

Tags: php, replace, callback, preg-replace

Error:

```
preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead
```

Code:

```
function convert_url_to_bbcode($messagetext){
$skiptaglist = 'url|email|code|php|html|noparse';

return preg_replace(
    '#(^|\[/(' . $skiptaglist . ')\])(.*(\[(' . $skiptaglist . ')|$))#siUe',
    "convert_url_to_bbcode_callback('\\3', '\\1')",
    $messagetext
); }
```

Any ideas? By the way, I have 0 php experience. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

The message is self explanatory,  use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and pass the code as anonymous function instead of putting the code in the regexp string:

```
return preg_replace(
    '#(^|\[/(' . $skiptaglist . ')\])(.*(\[(' . $skiptaglist . ')|$))#siU',
    function ($ match) { return convert_url_to_bbcode_callback($m[3], $m[1]); },
    $messagetext
);
```